# Chapter Opener in both Right and Left Side

Tags: macros, tikz-styles

I would like to get the below chapter opener with back-end Image in my LaTeX file.

```
1) BackEnd Image
2) Front End Chapter Number and Chapter Title.
3) Yellow Color box is backend and what you will learn and asian curriculum is front-end.
4) list text-content is front-end.
```

My MWE IS:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany,svgnames,x11names]{book}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
   paperwidth=216mm, paperheight=303mm,
   left=23mm,
   right=18mm,
   top=23mm, bottom=23mm,
   headheight=\baselineskip,
   headsep=7mm,
   footskip=10mm
}
\definecolor{chapopcolor}{cmyk}{.18,0,1,0}

\newcommand\chapterillustration{}

\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0pt}{
\ThisULCornerWallPaper{1}{\chapterillustration}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]
  \fill[chapopcolor,opacity=1]
  (current page.north west) rectangle 
  ([yshift=-3cm] current page.north east);
  \strictpagecheck\checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,
      xshift=20mm,yshift=-30mm,
      font=\sffamily\bfseries\huge] 
      at (current page.north west) 
      {\fontsize{16}{18}\selectfont\textcolor{white}{\chaptername}\     \thechapter};
    \node[text=blue,
      font=\fontsize{32}{34}\selectfont, 
      inner ysep=12pt, inner xsep=20pt,
      rounded rectangle,anchor=east, 
      xshift=-20mm,yshift=-30mm] 
      at (current page.north east) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \else {
    \ThisLLCornerWallPaper{.35}{fern_mo_01}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,
      xshift=-20mm,yshift=-30mm,
      font=\sffamily\bfseries\huge] 
      at (current page.north east)
      {\chaptername\ \thechapter};
    \node[fill=Sienna!80!black,text=white,
      font=\Huge\bfseries,
      inner sep=12pt, inner xsep=20pt,
      rounded rectangle,anchor=west,
      xshift=20mm,yshift=-30mm] 
      at ( current page.north west) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \fi
}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{135mm}





\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}

\renewcommand\chapterillustration{six-computers-chips-circuits}

\chapter{Chapter TeXt Here}

\section*{What you will learn}
\section*{Asian curriculum}

\begin{itemize}
\item[1A] Number Systems
\item[1B] Place value
\item[1C] Addition and subtraction
\item[1D] Addition and subtraction
\item[1E] Multiplication
\item[1F] Multiplying larger numbers
\item[1G] Division
\item[1I] Estimating and rounding Order of operations
\end{itemize}

\section*{Statistics and Probability}

\begin{itemize}
\item Data measures Determine mean, median, and range
and use these measures to compare
data sets explaining reasoning
\item Data investigation
Investigate questions involving the
collection of univariate and simple
bivariate data
\item Sample space
Construct sample spaces for single-
step experiments
\item Relative frequency
Calculate relative frequencies, and recognise variation between results
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: what do you mean by *from right and left side*?

Answer (score 3):

If you desire to align the text into two side-by-side sections you can use `minipages`:

[image]

### Notes:

- For the `minipage` on the right you had used an `itemize` which adds bullets for the list items, but as you show numbers in your image, I changed that to `enumerate`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany,svgnames,x11names]{book}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
   paperwidth=216mm, paperheight=303mm,
   left=23mm,
   right=18mm,
   top=23mm, bottom=23mm,
   headheight=\baselineskip,
   headsep=7mm,
   footskip=10mm
}
\definecolor{chapopcolor}{cmyk}{.18,0,1,0}

\newcommand\chapterillustration{}

\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0pt}{
\ThisULCornerWallPaper{1}{\chapterillustration}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]
  \fill[chapopcolor,opacity=1]
  (current page.north west) rectangle 
  ([yshift=-3cm] current page.north east);
  \strictpagecheck\checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,
      xshift=20mm,yshift=-30mm,
      font=\sffamily\bfseries\huge] 
      at (current page.north west) 
      {\fontsize{16}{18}\selectfont\textcolor{white}{\chaptername}\\
 \thechapter};
    \node[text=blue,
      font=\fontsize{32}{34}\selectfont, 
      inner ysep=12pt, inner xsep=20pt,
      rounded rectangle,anchor=east, 
      xshift=-20mm,yshift=-30mm] 
      at (current page.north east) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \else {
    \ThisLLCornerWallPaper{.35}{../images/EiffelTall}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,
      xshift=-20mm,yshift=-30mm,
      font=\sffamily\bfseries\huge] 
      at (current page.north east)
      {\chaptername\ \thechapter};
    \node[fill=Sienna!80!black,text=white,
      font=\Huge\bfseries,
      inner sep=12pt, inner xsep=20pt,
      rounded rectangle,anchor=west,
      xshift=20mm,yshift=-30mm] 
      at ( current page.north west) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \fi
}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{135mm}





\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}

\renewcommand\chapterillustration{../images/EiffelWide}

\chapter{Chapter TeXt Here}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
\section*{What you will learn}

\begin{itemize}
\item[1A] Number Systems
\item[1B] Place value
\item[1C] Addition and subtraction
\item[1D] Addition and subtraction
\item[1E] Multiplication
\item[1F] Multiplying larger numbers
\item[1G] Division
\item[1I] Estimating and rounding Order of operations
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}\raggedright
\section*{Asian curriculum}
\section*{Statistics and Probability}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Data measures Determine mean, median, and range
and use these measures to compare
data sets explaining reasoning
\item Data investigation
Investigate questions involving the
collection of univariate and simple
bivariate data
\item Sample space
Construct sample spaces for single-
step experiments
\item Relative frequency
Calculate relative frequencies, and recognize variation between results
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would like to put figure backend to `minipage` and frondend text is `list`. how to move `chapter box` to the center of the image?

Comment: @Balaji: I am not sure I understand what you are asking. If that has to do with text both on left and right side, then please edit the question and elaborate on what you mean. If it has to do with placing figures behind text, that should be a separate question as that is independent of placing text side by side.

Comment: i have updated my question.

Comment: I have posted with image in separate questions. Please see <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214568/spread-image-pages-in-chapter-opener>. This is my requirement.