# Spread Image Pages in Chapter Opener

Tags: graphics, chapters, backgrounds, book-design

Chapter Opener Image is full page image. I have need to `mask` half page image and frond-end would like to put some text. I'm expecting the output (see screenshot). How do achieve this in `LaTeX/XeLaTeX`. I had searched and found only `figure caption` [Unusual graphics and caption placement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54065/unusual-graphics-and-caption-placement).

1. 1Half-Page Image is BackEnd.

   a) Put the Chapter Number and Chapter Title in Front End of the Half-Page Image.
2. After Half-Page Image, Yellow Color box is back-end.
3. 2Half-Page Image is BackEnd.

   a) list text put in front of the second-half page in front-end text.

[image]

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany,svgnames,x11names]{book}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
   paperwidth=216mm, paperheight=303mm,
   left=23mm,
   right=18mm,
   top=23mm, bottom=23mm,
   headheight=\baselineskip,
   headsep=7mm,
   footskip=10mm
}
\definecolor{chapopcolor}{cmyk}{.18,0,1,0}

\newcommand\chapterillustration{}

\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0pt}{
\ThisULCornerWallPaper{1}{\chapterillustration}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]
  \fill[chapopcolor,opacity=1]
  (current page.north west) rectangle 
  ([yshift=-3cm] current page.north east);
  \strictpagecheck\checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,
      xshift=20mm,yshift=-30mm,
      font=\sffamily\bfseries\huge] 
      at (current page.north west) 
      {\fontsize{16}{18}\selectfont\textcolor{white}{\chaptername}\     \thechapter};
    \node[text=blue,
      font=\fontsize{32}{34}\selectfont, 
      inner ysep=12pt, inner xsep=20pt,
      rounded rectangle,anchor=east, 
      xshift=-20mm,yshift=-30mm] 
      at (current page.north east) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \else {
    \ThisLLCornerWallPaper{.35}{fern_mo_01}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,
      xshift=-20mm,yshift=-30mm,
      font=\sffamily\bfseries\huge] 
      at (current page.north east)
      {\chaptername\ \thechapter};
    \node[fill=Sienna!80!black,text=white,
      font=\Huge\bfseries,
      inner sep=12pt, inner xsep=20pt,
      rounded rectangle,anchor=west,
      xshift=20mm,yshift=-30mm] 
      at ( current page.north west) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \fi
}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{135mm}





\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}

\renewcommand\chapterillustration{six-computers-chips-circuits}

\chapter{Chapter TeXt Here}

\section*{What you will learn}
\section*{Asian curriculum}

\begin{itemize}
\item[1A] Number Systems
\item[1B] Place value
\item[1C] Addition and subtraction
\item[1D] Addition and subtraction
\item[1E] Multiplication
\item[1F] Multiplying larger numbers
\item[1G] Division
\item[1I] Estimating and rounding Order of operations
\end{itemize}

\section*{Statistics and Probability}

\begin{itemize}
\item Data measures Determine mean, median, and range
and use these measures to compare
data sets explaining reasoning
\item Data investigation
Investigate questions involving the
collection of univariate and simple
bivariate data
\item Sample space
Construct sample spaces for single-
step experiments
\item Relative frequency
Calculate relative frequencies, and recognise variation between results
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: related [Chapter Opener in both Right and Left Side](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/213691)

Comment: @Johannes_B: I have checked the link and that's not related my questions...

Comment: @Balaji That link surely is relevant, isn't it? It is your question and you are asking about precisely the same thing. I don't mean this is a duplicate but you are asking different questions about steps to complete the same chapter opening page. It would be good to edit that link into your question - code there might well help people trying to answer your question here.

Comment: Does the [following](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/206982/10274) help?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45120/ or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70379/ help? Note that your description still makes no sense to me and I'm completely unclear how the image relates to either it or the code. But those links show you have to split images, which is apparently what you are trying to do. I've deleted my answer as it doesn't apply to the current version of your question.

Comment: Is this really a duplicate of the linked question? Surely a float is not going to work well here? I admit, however, to being very unclear what the question is asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is based on [Peter Grill's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213707/) to your earlier question.

Note that I'm not sure quite what it is meant to look like since neither the first image you posted nor the second corresponds to the content of the MWE. Moreover, I still have absolutely zero idea what your description means, and you have not even attempted to clarify this.

## EDIT: An Unholy Cross Between the MWE & the 'Brazil' Image

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany,svgnames,x11names,a4paper]{book}% paper added to match image used for testing
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
%   paperwidth=216mm, paperheight=303mm,% changed just for illustration so the background image fits the page
  left=23mm,
  right=18mm,
  top=23mm, bottom=23mm,
  headheight=\baselineskip,
  headsep=7mm,
  footskip=10mm,
}
\definecolor{chapopcolor}{cmyk}{.18,0,1,0}

\newcommand\chapterillustration{}

\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0pt}{
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \node [anchor=south west, chapter pic] at (current page.south west) {\includegraphics[scale=1.414,angle=90]{\chapterillustration}};
      \fill[chapopcolor,opacity=1] ([yshift=15mm] current page.west) rectangle ([yshift=-30mm] current page.east);
      \fill[chapopcolor,opacity=.75] ([yshift=-30mm] current page.west) rectangle (current page.south east);
      \node (chapter name) [anchor=south east, chapter name] at (current page.east) {\chaptername};
      \node [chapter number] {\thechapter};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \afterpage{%
      \clearpage
        \thispagestyle{empty}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
          \node [anchor=south east, chapter pic] at (current page.south east) {\includegraphics[scale=1.414,angle=90]{\chapterillustration}};
          \fill[chapopcolor,opacity=1] ([yshift=15mm] current page.west) rectangle ([yshift=-30mm] current page.east);
          \fill[chapopcolor,opacity=.75] ([yshift=-30mm] current page.west) rectangle (current page.south east);
          \node (chapter text) [chapter text, anchor=south west] at ([xshift=50mm] current page.west) {#1};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \vspace*{135mm}%\dimexpr.5\textheight+30mm}
        \section*{}%
    }%
}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{135mm}

\tikzset{
  chapter pic/.style={
    inner sep=0pt,
    outer sep=0pt,
    opacity=.5
  },
  chapter name/.style={
    xshift=-25mm,
    yshift=30mm,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries\Huge,
    text=white},
  chapter number/.style={
    right=0pt of chapter name,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries\Huge,
    white,
    scale=2.5
  },
  chapter text/.style={
    fill=Sienna!80!black,
    text=white,
    font=\Huge\bfseries,
    inner ysep=12pt,
    inner xsep=20pt,
    rounded rectangle,
    xshift=-20mm,
    yshift=7.5mm
  },
}

\newlist{topiclist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[topiclist]{format=\color{blue}\sffamily\bfseries, label=\arabic*}
\newlist{curriculumlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[curriculumlist]{format=\color{blue}\sffamily\bfseries, label=\thechapter\Alph*}

\newenvironment{curriculum}[1]{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.8\linewidth}
      \subsection*{\color{blue}#1}
      \begin{curriculumlist}
  }{%
      \end{curriculumlist}
    \end{minipage}
  }
\newenvironment{topics}[1]{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.8\linewidth}\raggedright
      \subsection*{\color{blue}#1}
      \begin{topiclist}
  }{%
      \end{topiclist}
    \end{minipage}
  }

\begin{document}
  \pagestyle{headings}

  \renewcommand\chapterillustration{enfys}

  \chapter{Chapter TeXt Here}

  \section*{What you will learn}

  % ref. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213707/
  % Peter Grill's answer

    \begin{curriculum}{Asian curriculum}
      \item Number Systems
      \item Place value
      \item Addition and subtraction
      \item Addition and subtraction
      \item Multiplication
      \item Multiplying larger numbers
      \item Division
      \item Estimating and rounding Order of operations
    \end{curriculum}
    \clearpage
  \begin{topics}{Statistics and Probability}
    \item Data measures Determine mean, median, and range and use these measures to compare data sets explaining reasoning
    \item Data investigation
    Investigate questions involving the collection of univariate and simple bivariate data
    \item Sample space
    Construct sample spaces for single-step experiments
    \item Relative frequency
    Calculate relative frequencies, and recognize variation between results
  \end{topics}

\end{document}
```

[image: split pic]

## ORIGINAL: Based on the MWE & the Image Originally Posted

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany,svgnames,x11names,a4paper]{book}% paper added to match image used for testing
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\usepackage{changepage,enumitem}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
%   paperwidth=216mm, paperheight=303mm,% changed just for illustration so the background image fits the page
  left=23mm,
  right=18mm,
  top=23mm, bottom=23mm,
  headheight=\baselineskip,
  headsep=7mm,
  footskip=10mm
}
\definecolor{chapopcolor}{cmyk}{.18,0,1,0}

\newcommand\chapterillustration{}

\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0pt}{
  \ThisULCornerWallPaper{1}{\chapterillustration}
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture]
    {
      \fill[chapopcolor,opacity=1] ([yshift=15mm] current page.west) rectangle ([yshift=-15mm] current page.east);
      \fill[chapopcolor,opacity=.75] ([yshift=-15mm] current page.west) rectangle (current page.south east);
    }
  \strictpagecheck\checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \node (chapter name) [anchor=south west, chapter name] at (current page.west) {\chaptername};
      \node [chapter number] {\thechapter};
      \node (chapter text) [chapter text, anchor=south east] at (current page.east) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \else {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \node (chapter name) [anchor=south east, chapter name] at (current page.east) {\chaptername};
      \node [chapter number] {\thechapter};
      \node (chapter text) [chapter text, anchor=south west] at ( current page.west) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \fi
}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{135mm}

\tikzset{
  chapter name/.style={
    xshift=5mm,
    yshift=30mm,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries\Huge,
    text=white},
  chapter number/.style={
    right=0pt of chapter name,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries\Huge,
    white,
    scale=2.5
  },
  chapter text/.style={
    fill=Sienna!80!black,
    text=white,
    font=\Huge\bfseries,
    inner ysep=12pt,
    inner xsep=20pt,
    rounded rectangle,
    xshift=-20mm,
    yshift=7.5mm
  },
}

\newlist{topiclist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[topiclist]{format=\color{blue}\sffamily\bfseries, label=\arabic*}
\newlist{curriculumlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[curriculumlist]{format=\color{blue}\sffamily\bfseries, label=\thechapter\Alph*}

\newenvironment{curriculum}[1]{%
    \section*{\color{blue}#1}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
      \begin{curriculumlist}
  }{%
      \end{curriculumlist}
    \end{minipage}
  }
\newenvironment{topics}[1]{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}\raggedright
      \subsection*{\color{blue}#1}
      \begin{topiclist}
  }{%
      \end{topiclist}
    \end{minipage}
  }

\begin{document}
  \pagestyle{headings}

  \renewcommand\chapterillustration{enfys}

  \chapter{Chapter TeXt Here}

  \section*{What you will learn}

  % ref. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213707/
  % Peter Grill's answer

    \begin{curriculum}{Asian curriculum}
      \item Number Systems
      \item Place value
      \item Addition and subtraction
      \item Addition and subtraction
      \item Multiplication
      \item Multiplying larger numbers
      \item Division
      \item Estimating and rounding Order of operations
    \end{curriculum}
  \begin{topics}{Statistics and Probability}
    \item Data measures Determine mean, median, and range and use these measures to compare data sets explaining reasoning
    \item Data investigation
    Investigate questions involving the collection of univariate and simple bivariate data
    \item Sample space
    Construct sample spaces for single-step experiments
    \item Relative frequency
    Calculate relative frequencies, and recognize variation between results
  \end{topics}

\end{document}
```

[image: rainbow chapter]

Comment: How to spread the images? My Image is starting from `1st page` and ending with `2nd page` (i.e., Image is Spreading to two side pages).

Comment: @Balaji Sorry but I don't understand your question. Your picture shows a single page. I just went by that since I didn't understand your description at all.

Comment: I have updated my questions. I have need to `spread the images` in two pages (like page no 1 and page no 2). How do achive this..

Comment: @Balaji I dare say you'll post a third image bearing no more relation to your MWE or your (to me unintelligible) description, but for whatever little it is worth, I've updated my post showing how to *split* an image between the two pages, which I guess might possibly be what you mean by 'spread'. But, really, who knows?

Comment: @Balaji Note that I've scaled and faded the image I was using since I don't have an A3 image to hand other than the `mwe` one which makes it difficult to see what I'm doing. So you will want to remove this scaling (and maybe remove the angle of rotation) if adapting this code.